# Iterating through multiple values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list and dictionary of words:

```
word_list = ["it's","they're","there's","he's"]
```

And a dictionary containing information as to how frequently the words in `words_list` appear in several documents:

```
dict = [('document1',{"it's": 0,"they're": 2,"there's": 5,"he's": 1}),
('document2',{"it's": 4,"they're": 2,"there's": 3,"he's": 0}),
('document3',{"it's": 7,"they're": 0,"there's": 4,"he's": 1})]
```

I want to develop a data structure (data frame, perhaps?) that looks like the following:

```
file       word       count
document1  it's        0
document1  they're     2
document1  there's     5
document1  he's        1
document2  it's        4
document2  they're     2
document2  there's     3
document2  he's        0
document3  it's        7
document3  they're     0
document3  there's     4
document3  he's        1
```

I'm trying to find the `words` used most often in these documents. I have more than 900 documents.

I'm thinking of something like the following:

```
res = {}
for i in words_list:
    count = 0
    for j in dict.items():
         if i == j:
              count = count + 1
              res[i,j] = count
```

Where can I go from here?

Comment: You should use the Python Pandas lib to create the type of data frame you're showing in your post.

Comment: Where do I start with that? Any methods I should be looking at?

Comment: Making a variable named `dict` will make the builtin `dict` function inaccessible. You should rename it to something else. Also it's not a dict, it's a list of tuples of strings and dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first things first, your dict is not a dict and should be built as one like so

```
d = {'document1':{"it's": 0,"they're": 2,"there's": 5,"he's": 1},
    'document2':{"it's": 4,"they're": 2,"there's": 3,"he's": 0},
    'document3':{"it's": 7,"they're": 0,"there's": 4,"he's": 1}}
```

now that we actually have a dictionary we can use pandas to build a dataframe but in order to get it the way you want we will have to build a list of lists out of the dictionary. Then we will create a dataframe and label the columns and then sort

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

d = {'document1':{"it's": 0,"they're": 2,"there's": 5,"he's": 1},
    'document2':{"it's": 4,"they're": 2,"there's": 3,"he's": 0},
    'document3':{"it's": 7,"they're": 0,"there's": 4,"he's": 1}}

d = pd.DataFrame([[k,k1,v1] for k,v in d.items() for k1,v1 in v.items()], columns = ['File','Words','Count'])
print d.sort(['File','Count'], ascending=[1,1])

         File    Words  Count
1   document1     it's      0
0   document1     he's      1
3   document1  they're      2
2   document1  there's      5
4   document2     he's      0
7   document2  they're      2
6   document2  there's      3
5   document2     it's      4
11  document3  they're      0
8   document3     he's      1
10  document3  there's      4
9   document3     it's      7
```

If you want the top n occurrences then you can use `groupby()` and then either `head() or tail()` when sorting

```
d = d.sort(['File','Count'], ascending=[1,1]).groupby('File').head(2)

         File    Words  Count
1   document1     it's      0
0   document1     he's      1
4   document2     he's      0
7   document2  they're      2
11  document3  they're      0
8   document3     he's      1
```

the list comprehension returns a list of lists that looks like this

```
d = [['document1', "he's", 1], ['document1', "it's", 0], ['document1', "there's", 5], ['document1', "they're", 2], ['document2', "he's", 0], ['document2', "it's", 4], ['document2', "there's", 3], ['document2', "they're", 2], ['document3', "he's", 1], ['document3', "it's", 7], ['document3', "there's", 4], ['document3', "they're", 0]]
```

in order to build the dictionary properly you would just use something along the lines of

```
d['document1']['it\'s'] = 1
```

If for some reason you are dead set on using the list of tuples of str's and dicts you can use this list comprehension instead

```
[[i[0],k1,v1] for i in d for k1,v1 in i[1].items()]
```

Comment: Great answer. One question: the `d.sort(['File','Count'], ascending=[1,1])` also changes the index. Any particular reason why you wanted to do that?

Comment: @JoeR I just changed it so the files where in order from low to high and then the counts where set to do the same. It's not necessary but I thought it looked a little better.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
word_list = ["it's","they're","there's","he's"]

frequencies = [('document1',{"it's": 0,"they're": 2,"there's": 5,"he's": 1}),
('document2',{"it's": 4,"they're": 2,"there's": 3,"he's": 0}),
('document3',{"it's": 7,"they're": 0,"there's": 4,"he's": 1})]

result = []
for document in frequencies:
    for word in word_list:
        result.append({"file":document[0], "word":word,"count":document[1][word]})

print result
```

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` with that. I can't use the word itself to index

Comment: Are you running the code with the same data that I am? The only place that could be failing is on `document[1][word]`, and all of the keys in `document[1]` are strings in the provided data. Shouldn't fail. Edit: on second thought that error means your trying to access an element of a string with another string. Does your `frequencies` contain any raw strings?

Comment: I don't think so. It literally looks like that, although much more simplified from the actual data I'm using.. It follows the exact same syntactic structure, but `frequencies` is just way easier to talk about

Comment: Yeah, the code without `"count":document[1][word]` words fine.

Comment: run this: `[x for x in frequencies if type(x[1]) is str]` and see if anything shows up

Comment: I get back `['document1','document2',document3']`

Comment: You do have some raw strings in there somewhere. Search through your data for those strings and check if they're different from the rest of your data. (I would literally just cmd-f 'document1' and see what happens.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94250/discussion-between-jephron-and-gbr24).